# Cannot load assembly or dependencies with ClearScript.V8

Tags: c#, .net, v8, clearscript

I am started a project with ClearScript.V8.
I am developing on Windows 10 & Visual Studio 2015 in C#. The web is IISExpress and this will eventually be released on a Windows 2012 server.
I added the package ClearScript.V8 (v5.4.9) using NuGet. I always get the error below right from the start, not even initializing ClearScript yet (yes it's in french but it should be easy to understand):

> Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'ClearScriptV8-32.DLL'
>   ou une de ses dépendances. Le module spécifié est introuvable.
>
> Description : Une exception non gérée s'est produite au moment de
>   l'exécution de la requête Web actuelle. Contrôlez la trace de la pile
>   pour plus d'informations sur l'erreur et son origine dans le code.
>
> Détails de l'exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Impossible de
>   charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'ClearScriptV8-32.DLL' ou une de ses
>   dépendances. Le module spécifié est introuvable.
>
> Erreur source:
>
> Une exception non gérée s'est produite lors de l'exécution de la
>   requête Web actuelle. Les informations relatives à l'origine et
>   l'emplacement de l'exception peuvent être identifiées en utilisant la
>   trace de la pile d'exception ci-dessous.
>
> Trace de la pile:
>
> [FileNotFoundException: Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly
>   'ClearScriptV8-32.DLL' ou une de ses dépendances. Le module spécifié
>   est introuvable.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +36
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +21    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Impossible de charger le fichier ou
>   l'assembly 'ClearScriptV8-32.DLL' ou une de ses dépendances. Le module
>   spécifié est introuvable.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +217    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +130
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +170
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +92    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +549
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Impossible de charger le fichier ou
>   l'assembly 'ClearScriptV8-32.DLL' ou une de ses dépendances. Le module
>   spécifié est introuvable.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10044576
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254
>
> Informations sur la version : Version Microsoft .NET Framework
>   :4.0.30319; Version ASP.NET :4.7.2046.0

I followed instructions from https://microsoft.github.io/ClearScript/Details/Build.html (especially section IV), so I have files ClearScript.dll, ClearScriptV8-32.dll, ClearScriptV8-64.dll, v8-ia32.dll and v8-x64.dll in my bin folder. I also have ClearScriptV8-32.dll and ClearScriptV8-64.dll in my root folder (with Copy to Output = Do not copy).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting **all** of those DLLs (ClearScriptV8-*.dll, v8-*.dll) into the root folder, and make sure you do **not** have copies in `bin`. And if you're deploying onto a machine without Visual Studio (or with Visual Studio but without C++ support), install the appropriate version of Visual C++ Redistributable (it has to match the compiler used to build ClearScript).

Comment: Same issue with all files in root, no copies in bin.

Comment: Make sure you have `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Do not copy` for all of those files. If you're still seeing a problem at app startup (within `LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory`), post another stack trace.

Comment: This completely baffle me.
Just to be sure I recreated a new project from scratch using Visual Studio 2015, added ClearScript.V8 and nothing else and still get the same error.
I just don't understand how it's supposed to work if I move or duplicates DLL At some point you seem to suggest the web should not have any of the specified dll if there is no copy in bin and I don't copy to Output dir. Why does it try to use -32.dll if I run on x64? Why is this package so complicated to use when it should be straightforward?

Comment: The core problem is that these DLLs aren't managed. V8 is native, and ClearScriptV8 is mixed. At startup, ASP.NET pre-loads all DLLs in `bin`, and such DLLs make it fail. The solution is to remove them from `bin` and make sure they aren't copied there during deployment. Another solution is to exclude them from pre-loading (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6st6fhzz(v=vs.100).aspx)).

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006449/error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-manageddataaccessdtc-or-one-of-i) for a similar issue.

Comment: When I remove the files from bin, they reappear after a build.

Comment: Check for a custom build step that copies those files; sometimes NuGet packages add those. And, as I mentioned, if nothing else works, you should be able to exclude those files explicitly in web.config.

Comment: It starts to make more sense now. Thanks for all the explanations.
I can't believe that, in 2017, there is no way to make a package that makes a standard build that checks if those files need to be copied (or at least that works in 95% cases). I don't have a development setup that is so special...

For those looking here to get more info, the custom build steps are located in the project properties->Build Events->Post-build events.